# Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit freezing

Tags: boot

What happens is, when I boot my computer, it loads the login screen just fine. I proceed to type in my password and as soon as I type my password in, my mouse and keyboard freeze up and cannot be used, as if they're not even plugged in. I've reinstalled the OS a few times and I'm having the same problem each time. P.S. It tells me that something is disabled in bios. Does that have to do with anything? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver problem to me. What hardware do you run? Have tried to use the [recovery-mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)?

Answer (score -1):

Re download the ISO and install all updates,

also do 64 bit instead if you have [AMD] or [intel equip that is newer than 2007].

Comment: I find it very unlikely that the install is faulty because of the ISO. If you suspect it to be broken, then do a [integrity check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) redoing is the whole thing is unnecessary. Also,32-bit installation will work fine on a 64-bit computer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's a bug in the updates somewhere. I installed ubuntu from the cd and didn't connect to the Internet and didn't install any updates at first. It was working fine and when I went to install the updates, it told me to reboot and I would do so. When I type in my password and log in, about 15 seconds later my mouse and keyboard freezes up. The computer doesn't freeze I don't think because I see it continue to load its things. Also when I push the physical power button, it asks me if in sure I want to turn it off that way, so I'm pretty sure it's something with the mouse &kb

Comment: My CPU is Intel Core 2 Quad and my Graphics Card is a AMD Radeon HD 6770 Thanks